# Finite meaure space with $f \in L^p$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Given a finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$, for $1<p<\infty$,

if $f \in L^p(X)$, then $f \in L^1(X)$.

---

Can anyone show me how to start the proof?

Thanks.

Comment: Holder inequality

Comment: $|f|^p > |f|$ when $|f| > 1.$ Or use Holder.

Comment: Intuitively, we have that if $f \in L^p(X)$ the function does not have a bad singularity. The way $f$ would fail to be in $L^1$ if it does not converge to zero fast enough as $|x| \to \infty$. Notice that on a set of finite measure we will not have such a problem.